# Problems in deploying Access 2013 Application

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS-Access 2013 application (.accdb) with only couple of tables and forms in it. I am trying to deploy it on another machine that has only MS-Access 2013 runtime installed. Problem is my access application opens up on that machine with a security warning but doesn't show any object in it. Not even access ribbon. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Have you selected a form for the "Display Form" setting from Access Options -> Current Database -> Application Options?

Comment: @HansUp's suggestion is a good one.  This is the default form that the db will display.  When you're using the runtime, the navigation pane will never be available.  So make sure the default form connects to all the other tables/forms/queries the user might need.

Answer (score 1):

Solution suggested by @HansUp and then explained by @PowerUser in comments, worked like a charm.